# android - unable to post large data via Uri.Builder

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I post my data via Uri.Builder to the server . I've a very large data in my variable , this is the data :

```
630#738#6589#7772#7771#7769#7768#7767#7766#7765#7764#7763#7762#7761#7760#7759#7758#7757#7756#7754#7755#7753#7752#7751#7750#7748#7749#7747#7746#7744#7745#7743#7742#7770#7739#7738#7736#7737#7735#7734#7732#7733#7731#7730#7728#7729#7727#7726#7724#7725#7723#7722#7720#7721#7719#7718#7716#7717#7715#7714#7710#7713#7708#7707#7705#7706#7704#7703#7701#7702#7700#7699#7697#7698#7695#7694#7692#7693#7691#7690#7689#7688#7686#7687#7685#7684#7683#7682#7680#7681#7679#7678#7676#7677#7674#7673#7670#7668#7667#7665#7666#7664#7663#7661#7662#7660#7659#7657#7658#7656#7654#7653#7652#7651#7650#7648#7649#7647#7646#7644#7645#7643#7641#7639#7640#7638#7637#7635#7636#7634#7633#7631#7632#7630#7629#7627#7628#7626#7625#7623#7624#7622#7621#7619#7620#7618#7617#7615#7616#7614#7613#7607#7612#7606#7605#7602#7603#7601#7600#7598#7599#7597#7596#7594#7593#7592#7589#7590#7588#7586#7584#7585#7583#7582#7580#7581#7579#7578#7576#7577#7574#7573#7571#7572#7570#7569#7567#7568#7566#7565#7563#7564#7562#7561#7559#7560#7541#7539#7537#7538#7536#7535#7533#7534#7532#7531#7529#7530#7527#7526#7524#7525#7523#7522#7521#7520#7519#7515#7514#7512#7513#7511#7510#7508#7507#7506#7505#7504#7502#7499#7498#7496#7494#7493#7492#7491#7489#7490#7488#7487#7486#7485#7483#7484#7480#7472#7469#7468#7465#7466#7464#7463#7462#7457#7455#7456#7453#7452#7451#7446#7450#7444#7443#7442#7441#7439#7440#7438#7437#7436#7434#7432#7433#7430#7429#7428#7427#7423#7405#7404#7406#7407#7403#7402#7399#7400#7397#7398#7396#7395#7392#7393#7391#3886#4706#5023#5512#5152#716#4078#3339#4622#2935#


Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
builder.appendQueryParameter("products", prds);
```

this is the async task I use for posting data :

```
 public HtmlPost(OnTaskFinished onTaskFinished, Boolean progressDialog,
                Activity ct,String pgText, String PostingQueries) {
    onOurTaskFinished = onTaskFinished;
    pdText=pgText;
    act=ct;
    progressbar=progressDialog;
    query=PostingQueries;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]); // enter your url here which to download
        Log.v("this",urls[0]);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);


        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(query);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        conn.connect();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                HTML_response+=line;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        err=true;
    }
    return HTML_response;
}
```

I've some other parameters and all of them receives in server correctly .it works fine and post data to my server. the problem is when I have that large data , I don't get "products" in my server buy if it has some amount of data I receive "products" in my server .

How can I handle it and send large amount of data ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) to handle your parameter. you just need to create an Interface